# Lining the columns of a report up in an EMail

Tags: javascript, html-email

I'm a teacher and I'm sending grade reports via the EMail function MailApp.sendEmail using  Googlescript.  For the body of the EMail I build a long variable.  The EMail contains a report:  One line per grade.  I need to line the columns of the report up.  Here's what I have right now (from an EMail received from Mailapp.sentMail:

Student: Kent, David School

### Assignment.........................................................................Assigned........Due........Grade

Shop Week: Video Worksheet, Work.................................................01-18........01-28........100%
Homework Quiz: Work..............................................................01-28........01-28........100%
Rolling Quiz: Work...............................................................01-28........01-28........100%
Classwork: Work..................................................................01-28........01-28........100%
Homework: Video Worksheet, Work to Energy........................................01-28........01-29........100%
Homework Quiz: Work to Energy....................................................01-29........01-29........100%
Rolling Quiz: Work to Energy......................................................01-29........01-29........100%
Classwork: Work to Energy........................................................01-29........01-29........100%
Homework: Intro to Energy........................................................01-29........01-30........100%

As you can see, the columns aren't lined up.  When I realized that HTML doesn't display multiple spaces, I made a feeble attempt by substituting "." for space.  I tried using "& nbsp;" and was able to add multiple spaces, but I'm still confounded by the fact that different characters occupy different amounts of horizontal space. This makes counting characters as I build a report line ineffective.

I need a way to build a report line that will, when viewed in an EMail, have lined up columns.

Comment: Can you paste your current code.

Comment: Why not just use a `<table>`?

Comment: To malpomene:  I don't know anything about tables.  Can you describe briefly how they work and perhaps point me to where I can learn about them?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: Nils:  Here's some code in which I' ve been experimenting with adding and counting characters to produce lines that will line up in a report.  I thought I was going to solve the problem when I used "& nbsp;" but then I tried running with a difference character "@" which displayed much wider in an EMail.

Comment: Melpomene  Thanks.  I've gotta run out for an hour or so, but I'll check out tables when I return.  Thanks again.

Comment: Nils, I"m new to Stack overflow.  When I tried to put some code into a comment, I was told that it's too long.  There must be a way to attach a file, but I can't find that function on the website.  Can you give me a tip?

Comment: I don't think you can attach a file here, then you need to link to it yourself, but i would not recommend that. You should take part of you code, that you have identified as the problem and then paste that.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqgZQm

Comment: But what you should do is use `<table>`, they are the best option when doing email html, since it is supported by most mail clients. It's the best way to structure your data, when doing emails, and your case seems like the perfect example to use it on. 
Take a look at [mailchimps post about it](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/)

Comment: @NilsKähler The funny thing is that it doesn't really matter that it's email. This is straight up tabular data, so `<table>` is the semantically correct HTML element to use. :-)

Comment: @melpomene yes i agree, that tables are semantically correct for tabular data, I'm also saying that his case is the perfect example for tables. I think we agree.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a code generator for tables at https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables

I created a table to my specifications (columns, row headers, etc.).  I entered a couple of rows with dummy data to get the HTML/CSS for creating the table, headers and rows.  Then I took that code and used it in my Javascript to build the string of text that I send to the utility MailApps to send and EMail.  It worked like a champ except for the fact that I need to make a couple of adjustments like changing row height.  I'm struggling to add the CSS code to change row height.